# Convert year 00 into year 2000 in Python

Tags: python, pandas

I have my DF born with the Month column:

Apr-90

In

```
df2['Month'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['Month'], format="%Y")
```

Out

```
Month   Pork Price  year    month

0   1990-04-01  99.64   1990.0  4.0

1   1990-05-01  115.68  1990.0  5.0
2   1990-06-01  121.46  1990.0  6.0
3   1990-07-01  96.19   1990.0  7.0
4   1990-08-01  93.97   1990.0  8.0
... ... ... ... ...
115 1999-11-01  47.66   1999.0  11.0
116 1999-12-01  50.94   1999.0  12.0
117 NaT 51.61   NaN NaN
118 NaT 54.91   NaN NaN
119 NaT 57.76   NaN NaN
```

My problem is that when the years changes to jan-00 my code is not sufficient.

I hope someone can help

Regards Jan

Comment: Please add more details and code to reproduce you data (MRE), so we can better help you. for guidelines on how to ask questions see: https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking

Answer (score 0):

Use the correct format string `%b-%y`, as follows:

```
df2['Month'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['Month'], format="%b-%y")
```

Refer to [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes) for the list of format strings.